# PostgreSQL - GROUP BY timestamp values?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, timestamp, group-by

I've got a table with purchase orders stored in it.  Each row has a timestamp indicating when the order was placed.  I'd like to be able to create a report indicating the number of purchases each day, month, or year.  I figured I would do a simple SELECT COUNT(xxx) FROM tbl_orders GROUP BY tbl_orders.purchase_time and get the value, but it turns out I can't GROUP BY a timestamp column.

Is there another way to accomplish this?  I'd ideally like a flexible solution so I could use whatever timeframe I needed (hourly, monthly, weekly, etc.)  Thanks for any suggestions you can give!

Comment: What error does it give you when you try to group by a timestamp column? It seems to work fine here, keeping in mind that the timestamps must be identical (down to the microsecond, or whatever the minimum resolution is) to be grouped.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Grouping by a timestamp column works fine for me here, keeping in mind that even a 1-microsecond difference will prevent two rows from being grouped together.

To group by larger time periods, group by an expression on the timestamp column that returns an appropriately truncated value. [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) can be useful here, as can [`to_char`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE).

Comment: The date_trunc function was exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

This does the trick without the date_trunc function (easier to read).

```
// 2014
select created_on::DATE from users group by created_on::DATE

// updated September 2018 (thanks to @wegry)
select created_on::DATE as co from users group by co
```

What we're doing here is casting the original value into a DATE rendering the time data in this value inconsequential.

Comment: exactly what i was looking for, converts to a date like "2016-06-27", easy to quick count(*) by day

Comment: I don't think type casting timestamp to DATE will work in Group By, as it is not working for me.

Comment: @hky404 I got this to work aliasing in the select and then using that alias in the GROUP BY. `select created_on::DATE as co from users group by co`

Comment: @wegry Thanks! I updated the answer with your solution. I'm guessing that Postgres updated in the 5 years since I posted that.

Comment: how does it work for month & year? it throws out an error for timestamp::month