# Grouping by month in database and not with ruby

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to group `calls` by month but I need to do it in the database and not with `ruby`. Here is the current code:

```
Call.limit(1000).group_by { |t| t.created_at.month }
```

Which returns:

```
SELECT `calls`.* FROM `calls` ORDER BY created_at desc LIMIT 1000
```

Then `ruby` does the grouping. What should I do to make the database do the work ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Call.limit(1000).group("month(created_at)")

Please checkout mysql date-time methods appropriate in your case. But .group() will do the mysql grouping.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month

Comment: The user is using PG, not MySQL.

Comment: oh okay in that case it  will not work. Try pgsql method:

EXTRACT(MONTH FROM TIMESTAMP '2001-02-16 20:38:40') instead of month.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer, is that you cannot achieve the same result at SQL level.

Here's the full explanation.

First of all, what should be the result of that call? You can use the PG/SQL [Group BY](http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-group-by/) statement, however it's likely the result is not what you expect.

The Group By syntax is designed to group rows with a pattern, and compute and aggregate function. In your case, even assuming you create a query that uses [`date_trunc`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TRUNC) to [group by a part of the timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6832566/postgresql-group-by-timestamp-values), the aggregate function does not permit you to return a dataset structured like the Ruby `group_by` method.

Why do you want to compute such grouping at database level?

If you have specific requirements or computation limits, then work on a custom method.